# Storing MySQL DB credentials in one file then calling that file in the main script

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I would like to create an credentials.py file which will be stored in the same directory as the main python script that holds my credentials for my MySQL DB connection.

```
credentials.py

host = '11.11.81.7011'
user = 'dsufghsd'
password = 'tfjb2379gfweiu'
db = 'fwenf249ftgwieufgefw7f'
```

Then while connecting to MySQL DB

```
import credentials
con = pymysql.connect(host = credentials.host,
                      user = credentials.user,
                      password = credentials.password,
                      db = credentials.db,
                      charset = 'utf8mb4', 
                      cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.SSDictCursor)
```

But I keep getting an import error saying that there is no module named "credentials

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: this is a bad idea, store them in your environment and call on them using `os.environ['KEY']`

Comment: @eagle, how would I go about doing this??

Comment: @MaxU, the file is in the current directory

Comment: what OS are you using

Comment: @eagle, I am using a Mac

Comment: whatever text editor you use, open your `~/.bash_profile` and then add these variables in i.e, `export SQL_HOST='11.11.81.7011'`...etc

Comment: Ahh, ok got ya. Then I just call them in the MySQL connection by `os.environ['KEY'] ?

Comment: @eagle, then what do I input into the `pymysql.connect()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your variables into your `~/.bash_profile` using whatever text editor you use

```
export SQL_HOST='11.11.81.7011'
export SQL_USER='dsufghsd'
export SQL_PWD='tfjb2379gfweiu'
export SQL_DB='fwenf249ftgwieufgefw7f'
```

Don't forget to do `source ~/.bash_profile`

Then you call on them as such

```
import os

conf = {'host': os.environ['SQL_HOST'],
        'user': os.environ['SQL_USER'],
        'password': os.environ['SQL_PWD'],
        'db': os.environ['SQL_DB']}

conf.update({'charset': 'utf8mb4',
             'cursorclass': pymysql.cursors.SSDictCursor})

conn = pymysql.connect(**conf)
```

Comment: I did everything you said and copied the code. I go to run it in my jupyter notebook and it gives me a key error on `SQL_HOST`

Comment: your notebook must be pointed at a different environment, that's on you how to configure that

Comment: Thanks for the help!